# log4cplus not printing file names and line numbers

Tags: log4cplus

I am using the [log4cplus](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/) library (v1.0.0) and the logger set up is as follows:

```
std::string formatString("%-5p [%F,%L] %m%n");
std::auto_ptr <log4cplus::Layout> layout(new log4cplus::PatternLayout(formatString));
logAppender->setLayout(layout);
```

I am using the following function to log:

```
log4cplus::Logger logger;
logger.log(INFO_LOG_LEVEL, msg);
```

The log message printed in the log is:

```
DEBUG [,] My log message
INFO  [,] My other log message
```

It does not print the file name or the line number in the log. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not passing any of the information into the `log()` function. The `log()` function is declared as follows:

```
void log(LogLevel ll, const log4cplus::tstring& message,
         const char* file=NULL, int line=-1) const;
```

As you can see, unless you provide the file and line information, it passes in "empty" values.

Either you pass the information down yourself or you include `log4cplus/loggingmacros.h` and use provided logging macros, which do that for you.